# Max number of object properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am considering using a javascript object as a site-wide key/value memory cache. Is there any limitations in amount of properties? How will this perform compared to, lets say, memcached?

```
cache['some-long-key-goes-here'] = 'possibly an entire page worth of html'
```

Comment: You will likely run into memory limits before language limits doing something like this.

Comment: Anything can run out of memory. Will it consume more than memcached? More overhead?

Comment: Based on a given node process' memory limits, it will run out of room before approaching memcached's limits.  You're asking a lot of grey area questions.  To put it clearer: "How will [this potential system that is yet to be written and benchmarked] perform compared to [this other system that is already written in a compiled language and well-known to be performant]?"

Comment: I don't agree that it's a grey area. Someone here definitely has enough knowledge about javascript and node.js to tell me whether or not this is a viable approach. It's not like I am asking how some complicated code will work, it's just a javascript object.

Comment: "How will it perform?" Are you going to add all of the features of memcached (https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewOverview). It's not apples-to-apples. You'll be limited to very little RAM in comparison as well. https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-memory-limit-on-a-node-process

Comment: How will it perform as nothing else than a key-value cache storage was the question, not how will it perform if I implemented a ton of extra features.